# SQL Joining the same tables together

Tags: sql, join

I want to join the 2 tables together. They are the same. But I need the joining because I added a foreign key constraint somewhere for takeoff and land. and they both reference my airport table. Now I want to display flight details including both takeoff airport details and landing airport details. And I have no idea how? This is what I have so far, it can only display takeoff details so far. When I try to add the airport.airport_id again, I get an error. See.

```
select * 
from flight 
LEFT JOIN route ON flight.route_id = route.route_id 
LEFT JOIN airport ON route.takeoff_id = airport.airport_id
```

gives me: 
[image]

But when I try this query to join the landing details

```
select * 
from flight 
LEFT JOIN route ON flight.route_id = route.route_id 
LEFT JOIN airport ON route.takeoff_id = airport.airport_id 
LEFT JOIN airport ON route.land_id = airport.airport_id;
```

I get this error: `#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'airport'`

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images only. I've added the error message as text now, so your request can be found when people with a similar problem search for this message.

Answer (score 2):

When working with the same table twice (self-join) you must use table aliases to show the DBMS of which of the two your are talking.

```
select * 
from flight 
join route ON flight.route_id = route.route_id 
join airport airport_takeoff ON route.takeoff_id = airport_takeoff.airport_id 
join airport airport_landing ON route.land_id = airport_landing.airport_id;
```

BTW: I've replaced your outer joins with inner joins, as I see no reason for outer joins here. You should not give the DBMS more to do than necessary.

Comment: Look at that, we posted at almost the same time, you're 36 seconds before me!

Comment: @Steve Ford: Yes, that was an easy one :-)

Answer (score 0):

To use the same table twice you need to alias them:

```
select * 
from flight 
LEFT JOIN route ON flight.route_id = route.route_id 
LEFT JOIN airport a1 ON route.takeoff_id = a1.airport_id 
LEFT JOIN airport a2 ON route.land_id = a2.airport_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below queries.

```
    select * 
    from flight  FL  -- alis as FL
    LEFT JOIN route RT ON FL.route_id = RT.route_id 
    LEFT JOIN airport AP1 ON RT.takeoff_id = AP1.airport_id  
    LEFT JOIN airport AP2 ON RT.land_id = AP2.airport_id;
```

OR

```
    select * 
    from flight 
    LEFT JOIN route ON flight.route_id = route.route_id 
    LEFT JOIN airport ON route.takeoff_id = airport.airport_id  and route.land_id = airport.airport_id;
```